# What are allowed symbols for naming perl5 modules and subroutines?

Tags: perl

Is it

`[A-Za-z]` and `::` for module names

and `[A-Za-z_-]` for subroutine names ?

P.S. I'm writing regex for parsing some debug output.

Answer (score 7):

See [perlvar](https://perldoc.pl/perlvar#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names); since named subroutines are just variables in the package stash, they have the same identifier requirements as other variables. [perldata](https://perldoc.pl/perldata#Identifier-parsing) has the full gritty details. Remember that unicode characters are valid in identifiers as long as you have `use utf8;` active which will decode your source code from UTF-8.

Package names are just part of variables names, so they have the same restrictions plus they can contain the `::` or `'` separators, however there is an additional practical restriction here for any module you `use`, because this converts it to a filename and then it's up to what your filesystem supports. Many parts of the CPAN toolchain are also not equipped to deal with non-ASCII package names. So it's generally not a good idea. There are some [Acme modules](https://metacpan.org/release/Acme-LookOfDisapproval) that test the waters here.

Essentially:

- if `use utf8` is not active, identifiers may consist of "any word character in the ASCII range, as long as the first character is not a digit." "Word character" here means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
- if `use utf8` is active, identifiers may start with a unicode "start" character or underscore, followed by unicode "continue" characters. All characters are additionally required to be unicode word characters.

The `-` hyphen is not valid in any identifiers (except punctuation identifiers mentioned below).

There are also "special identifiers", which consist of mostly special Perl globals: all-digit variables, variables consisting of a single punctuation character, variables consisting of `^` followed by a letter, and variables consisting of `^` followed by a word with required braces (such as `@{^CAPTURE}`). None of these are used for sigil-optional subroutines that I can recall.